# execute method periodically when I start server in j2ee

Tags: jakarta-ee, web.xml

I need to execute method periodically when I start server, I'm using Tomcat v6.0 Server, and as a frameworks, I use hibernate, JSF, Primefaces and spring.
Should I add something in web.xml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your application environment, you can add startup hook with any of the below ways.

- **Spring**

  You can implement [Lifecycle](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/Lifecycle.html) or [SmartLifeCycle](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html) interface for application context's startup and shutdown phases.
- **Tomcat**

  You can add listener by implementing [LifecycleListener](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/LifecycleListener.html)
- **Generic**

  1. [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html)
  2. Configuring servlet to load-on-startup.

Afterwards, you can add [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) to execute tasks periodically.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions, you can achive your need by one of this way.

Assume your method is a Dispatch task you scheduled to run once in some interval sec

Keep your task in separate class and schedule it after your context sucessfully initilized

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExcecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);
scheduledExcecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(yourTaskInstance, 0,
                                           sleepInterval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

You can schedulewith Fixed Rate also,check  [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) document

Shutdown it gracefully when your server is down.